# DataSource.groovy not found. grails 2.4.4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am getting this error while running the application. I am using postgres 9.4 database. I ensured that DataSource.groovy exists. I am on MAC OS X 10.10

```
grails> r-a
| Starting daemon...
| Compiling 450 source files
| Parent process shutdown. Exiting...
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
| Starting daemon.....
| Warning No config found for the application.
| Warning DataSource.groovy not found, assuming dataSource bean is configured by Spring
| Running Grails application
objc[2087]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
| Error 2015-04-10 12:24:40,201 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
Message: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: BootStrap
->>  366 | run       in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    355 | run       in     ''
|    354 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    425 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    262 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2015-04-10 12:24:40,261 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
Message: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: BootStrap
->>  366 | run       in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    355 | run       in     ''
|    354 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    425 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    262 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

| Error 2015-04-10 12:24:40,277 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR core.StandardContext  - Error listenerStart
    | Error 2015-04-10 12:24:40,288 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR core.StandardContext  - Context [/yazh] startup failed due to previous errors
    | Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/yazh
    | Application loaded in interactive mode. Type 'stop-app' to shutdown.
    | Enter a script name to run. Use TAB for completion: 
    | Parent process shutdown. Exiting...
    | Error Forked Grails VM exited with error

Comment: As far as I can see it's the `BootStrap.groovy` class that's not found.

Comment: @DaddyPumpkin BootStarp.groovy is also available under the config folder.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when there's an error in the Domain, Controller or Service classes. run with --stacktrace and you'll find the root cause

Answer (score 0):

This isn't much of an answer, but I just experienced this error and was able to get rid of it with a grails clean and grails compile.